# "Hotlinking is forbidden" ao usar file_get_contents()

Tags: php

Este erro aparece quando eu tento usar a função `file_get_contents()` do PHP:

> failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Hotlinking is forbidden

Como parâmetro temos uma página PHP normal, que faz algumas conexões ao banco de dados do cliente e um interno dele. Este *target* não tem *header* nenhum. Dependendo de o que ocorrer lá dentro (der tudo certo), ele vai "printar" (com echo) um JSON. E é isso que eu quero adquirir por meu do `file_get_contents`. Meu hotlink está desativado.

O que posso fazer para corrigir?

Comment: Eu sou o administrador do servidor.

Comment: Bom. No Target temos uma página PHP normal, que faz algumas conexões ao banco de dados do cliente e um interno dele. Este Target não tem header nenhum. Dependendo de o que ocorrer lá dentro ( der tudo certo), ele vai aprintar ( com echo ) um JSON. E é isso que eu quero adquirir por meu do file_get_contents. Meu hotlink está desativado.

Comment: Descreva essa explicação no corpo da pergunta, mas descreva de um jeito que pessoas alheias ao projeto possam entender.

Answer (score 4):

Normalmente os *hotlinks* são detectados pelo *header* `Referer` enviado pelo *browser*.

Para especificar um `header` no uso do `file_get_contents`, temos o `stream_context_create`:

```
$opts = array(
   'http'=>array(
      'header'=>'Referer: http://www.enderecodositerequisitado.com'."\r\n"
   )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$file = file_get_contents(
    'http://www.enderecodositerequisitado.com/caminho', false, $context
);
```

Desta forma, o comportamento fica similar a um acesso feito por um *link* do próprio site. Notar que a proteção pode ser mais complexa que isto, mas na maior parte dos casos, a solução é por este caminho.

No exemplo acima, o importante é que o `Referer` tenha como origem algo esperado no uso normal do site, por um usuário que esteja navegando normalmente.

Alternativamente, em vez de fazer isto tudo, poderia ser o caso de simplesmente colocar o IP do seu servidor em uma lista branca no servidor do lado que fornece os dados.

Comment: Resolvi de outra forma. O pessoal da minha hospedagem me deu uma ajudinha. Bastou colocar a porta 8080, para iniciar com o apache. exemplo: http://www.enderecodositerequisitado.com:8080

Comment: @RafaelAndersonlobo isso não é solução para o que foi perguntado. Se funcionou no seu caso, o problema é outro, e não tem nada a ver com o erro da pergunta.

Comment: Besteira. Eu postei o problema e a solução, então como o problema não seria este ?

Comment: Porque o problema não foi resolvido, foi contornado. Solução para bloqueio de hotlink não tem nada a ver com porta. Se tivesse proteção na 8080 dava na mesma. Você resolveu o problema de fazer funcionar, de fato. Mas nao tem nada a ver com o problema descrito na pergunta. Seria como perguntar "como removo arquivos duplicados do meu HD pq preciso de espaço", e depois voltar aqui e dizer "a solução é comprar outro HD". Que comprar outro HD resolve, a gente sabe, mas não tem nada a ver com remover arquivos duplicatos. Solucionou? Sim, mas não respondeu a pergunta inicial, falei nesse sentido.